# Using JavaScript NPM package with import

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using the kahoot-api NPM module ([GitHub](https://github.com/idiidk/kahoot-api), [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@omegaboot/kahoot-api)) and it requires using JavaScript import. (edit, this is a Node.js package. I didn't know the difference between JS and Node.js at the time of writing this, this is why this question was created).

The documentation says to use the following JavaScript import script to import `Session` and `Adapters`:

```js
import { Session, Adapters } from 'kahoot-api';
```

This throws an error saying that I need to use a relative reference.

> Failed to resolve module specifier "kahoot-api". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

My files and folders are structured as so:

> - index.php
> - node_modules
>
>   - @omegaboot
>
>     - kahoot-api

All of the NPM files for `kahoot-api` are inside of the `kahoot-api` folder.

I have modified my JavaScript code to use a relative reference, as shown below.

```js
import { Session, Adapters } from './node_modules/@omegaboot/kahoot-api/';
```

No errors are thrown, however the two imported statements `Session` and `Adapters` are not available, and still undefined.

```js
import { Session, Adapters } from './node_modules/@omegaboot/kahoot-api/';

const session = new Session('000000');
session.openSocket() //Connect
  .then(socket => {
    const player = new Adapters.Player(socket); //Create player class
    player.join('test') //Join with name
      .then(() => {
         console.log('Success!');
      });
  });
```

There are multiple JavaScript files inside of the `kahoot-api` folder, and I have tried including each JavaScript file with the JavaScript import, but to no avail.

Also, I am using the code in `index.php` with a `<script>` tag with the attribute `type="module"` as it is needed, or else the following error is thrown:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Are you using webpack? Because `import` statement does not support directly in nodejs.

Comment: @ajitkumar I have no idea what a webpack is. I just installed the npm package with npm install.

Comment: If you are not using any js bundlers then you should use `require('module-name')` instead of `import` statement.

Comment: I think the correct import statement should be this:
`import { Session, Adapters } from '@omegaboot/kahoot-api';`

Comment: @PatrickHund This just results in `Failed to resolve module specifier "@omegaboot/kahoot-api". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idiidk here (the author of the package)

The package `@omegaboot/kahoot-api` is not the version that people should be using. This package uses some hard coded defaults for easier integration with our build process for omegaboot.com.

The "normal" kahoot-api package https://www.npmjs.com/package/kahoot-api is to be used by third parties, although it hasn't been updated in a bit. Please open an issue on the github page if anything is broken and I'll be sure to take a look.

Comment: Yep, I understood. However, I was using this in normal JavaScript, so this is why these errors were here.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that documentation is wrong because it is based on an old package.

You should install it like:

```
yarn add @omegaboot/kahoot-api
```

or

```
npm i @omegaboot/kahoot-api
```

if you have webpack (I see that you are using this in php) then use import

```
import { Session, Adapters } from '@omegaboot/kahoot-api';
```

otherwise use require

```
const { Session, Adapters } = require("@omegaboot/kahoot-api")
```

Comment: I get a `Failed to resolve module specifier "@omegaboot/kahoot-api". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` when using the first example.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when I tried the module `@omegaboot/kahoot-api`.

As nodejs does not support import statement and you must use `require` method if you are not using any bundlers.

```js
const {
  Session,
  Adapters
} = require('@omegaboot/kahoot-api');

const session = new Session('000000');
session.openSocket() //Connect
  .then(socket => {
    const player = new Adapters.Player(socket); //Create player class
    player.join('test') //Join with name
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Success!');
      });
  });
```

Comment: I tried this exact thing with require.js (since require was not defined) and it just returns null (eruda says this, i do not have access to the real console, eruda is just a mobile console)

Comment: @4424dev I've have edited my answer try it out. It must work.

Comment: I just tried that, as I saw your edit. It still results in null. Session and Adapters are still undefined.

Comment: I am using require.js (as require is undefined)

Comment: Well, I think this module is for browser, right? If so you must use webpack or other bundlers that support `import` statement. I tried to build and and include the script in HTML file, but due to CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) is disabled on https://test.omegaboot.com/kahoot/ for local host. I think this what you need.

Comment: So I need to run on localhost? I try this on a shared hosting server. I also looked at https://webpack.js.org/ but have no idea what to do.

Comment: "I tried to build and and include the script in HTML file, but due to CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) is disabled on test.omegaboot.com/kahoot for localhost it showing error 404 (not found)" : edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205366/discussion-between-ajit-kumar-and-4424dev).